# iOS AVFoundation different presets for still image and preview

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

Is there a way to show preview (for example from modified frames) with a medium/low preset, and capture a still image with high/photo preset? Changing the preset doesn't work because it either fails or the camera fails to turn on in time..

I've seen a similar question here, seems as if it was already solved but I don't see how that would show a low quality preview and capture a high quality still image:

[Switching AVCaptureSession preset when capturing a photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055350/switching-avcapturesession-preset-when-capturing-a-photo)